# Cordova app showing 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.11.10

Tags: cordova, nginx, keycloak

I am using the Keycloak Javascript adapter to have my Android cordova app to authenticate with keycloak to my backend service. When my app launches, I goto the keycloak login URL and  keycloak login screen is properly displayed and authentication works fine. Then I press the back button to exit my app. When I relaunch my app, I again go to the keycloak login URL, but this time the keycloak login screen is not displayed. Instead, I see 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.11.10. I am unable to figure out if I am doing anything wrong in my app or if this is a problem with keycloak auth server. Thanx is advance for any help.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Are there any logs from nginx/keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where is your Nginx proxy located... If it is placed over your services (Backend) or it is placed over Keycloak.

BTW I will assume that you have a Keycloak behind a Nginx reverse proxy.

When you are previously logged in, browser sends a cookie to the Keycloak server and this is what you need to check.
Debug your Cordova application to provide info about calls to Keycloak (url, cookies, form parameters/headers and response code).

A good start point is to check that you have configure ok your nginx server following this tutorials: [redhat tutorial](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/08/configuring-nginx-keycloak-oauth-oidc/) (specially the referred to nginx.conf file)

Another good tutorial to check is: [nginx keycloak tutorial](https://edhull.co.uk/blog/2018-06-06/keycloak-nginx)

Initial versions of Keycloak may be possible that need to add to the nginx.conf this setting (there is an old related ticket about it) :

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

Try to provide more data about your problem (e.g. your nginx configuration) and maybe I can help you.

Comment: At least with my issue, I don't think it's due to nginx, as another client I've setup works fine. I think it might be an issue with the response type

Comment: Hi @CecilRodriguez check your keycloak server version and js adapter version (use same version to better support)... try to put your device in debug and submit some call traces. A request and response sample of your conversation with keycloak may be helpful (specially http response with 502 code)...